# How can I align text in colums automatically - C

Tags: c, ide, alignment

I want to aling C code in colums to make code more clear to read. Something like this:

```
foo = "abc";
bar1 = "defDEF";
baz = "ghi";
baz1 = "jklm";


foo  = "abc";
bar1 = "defDEF";
baz  = "ghi";
baz1 = "jklm";
```

I'm using Visual Studio.

My question is, how I can do this automatically without count spaces?

In particular I'm interested into a general way, something like windows related and not IDE related. If not possible it's also ok IDE related or a plugin.

Comment: I'd check out [Universal Indent](http://universalindent.sourceforge.net/), it is a free tool which gathers together lots of C "prettify" tools like GNU indent and provides a graphical UI for them. (GNU indent in itself is pretty good but lacks a few features here and there that other tools got.)

Answer (score 0):

This is really a sytle approach in that some coders use spaces to align code and others use tabs.  My personal opinion is to use tabs as that is really the whole point of them in that, it aligns text in columns.

The only real issue that can occur with tabs is that different IDE's and even versions of IDE's may display them slightly differently.  Tabs have no real defined size, so you can set the size of a tab so that it aligns code in columns and each tab will then skip to the alignment column that you've specified.

Usually a tab is set to 4 spaces or thereabouts.  It is usually a setting you can find within your chosen IDE as to how many spaces a tab represents.  Also, another reason why tabs, as opposed to spaces are especially good at aligning code is that if you are using a proportional font (where characters are each a different size) then the only real way to align code in columns is with tabs.  Using spaces to align code is usually mitigated by IDE's using a fixed width font, but this doesn't have to be the case.  In fact, using a proportional font and spaces would make aligning code in columns exceptionally problematic if not impossible.

But as I said, it's personal choice.  Most good IDE's will try to align your code in columns, but tabs are the usual convention for enforcing column spacing in source code.